# Vue-resource issue with $http - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: php, laravel-5, vue-resource

I am new to Vue and I am using it in a Laravel 5.3 project.

in my app.js file I have the following

```
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('CheckoutForm', require('./components/CheckoutForm.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

Then in my bootstrap file I have

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', admin.csrfToken);

  next();
});
```

In my CheckoutForm.vue file I have the template and the js as follows:

```
<template>
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST"     action="payments/checkout">
 <input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" v-model="stripeToken" />
 <input type="hidden" name="stripeEmail" v-model="stripeEmail" />

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <label> Select New Plan</label>
    <select name="plan" v-model="plan" class="form-control col-md-8" >
      <option v-for="plan in plans" :value="plan.id">
        {{ plan.name }} - ${{ plan.price / 100}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="buy">Proceed to Payment</button>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="/myaccount">Continue as Trial</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {

  props: ['plans'],
  data() {
      return{
        stripeEmail: '',
        stripeToken: '',
        plan: 3,
        status: false
      };
  },

  created(){
    this.stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: admin.stripeKey,
        image: "https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png",
        locale: "auto",
        panelLabel: "Subscribe for: ",
        email: admin.user.email,
        token: function(token){
          this.stripeEmail = token.email;
          this.stripeToken = token.id;

          //this.$el.submit();
          this.$http.post('payments/checkout', this.$data)
              .then(
                response => alert('Thank you for your purchase!.'),
                response => this.status = response.body.status
              );

        }
      });
  },

  methods: {

    buy(){

      let plan = this.findPlanById(this.plan);

      this.stripe.open({
        name: plan.name,
        description: plan.description,
        zipCode: true,
        amount: plan.price
      });
    },

    findPlanById(id){
      return this.plans.find(plan => plan.id == id);
    }

  }

};
```

The issue I am having is that my call to submit the form with this.$http.post() is giving me the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

And I think it is an issue with loading vue-resource.

I have checked that my **package.json** file has `vue-resource` and I have installed it via npm but still the same issue is present.

Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to tell `Vue` about `vue-resource`. Replace `require('vue-resource')` with `Vue.use(require('vue-resource'))` in your bootstrap file.

Comment: Hi Donkarnash, I tried that but I still got the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at TokenCallback.token [as fn] (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:84), <anonymous>:52:21)
    at TokenCallback.trigger (checkout.js:3)
    at TokenCallback.trigger (checkout.js:3)
    at IframeView.onToken (checkout.js:3)
    at IframeView.closed (checkout.js:3)
    at Object.closed (checkout.js:3)
    at RPC.processMessage (checkout.js:2)
    at RPC.processMessage (checkout.js:2)
    at RPC.message (checkout.js:2)
    at checkout.js:2

Comment: The error seems to be getting triggered from Stripe's checkout.js. Check the line 84 in your app.js and try to `console.log(this.$http)` before that line just to ensure that it is not a `Vue` error.

Answer (score 4):

Okay the problem is with your CheckoutForm.vue file in the script part  - in the `created() method` `token:function(token){}` **this** is not referencing the `Vue` instance hence `this.$http` is undefined.

Change it to use ES2015 arrow syntax as modified in your code below then you should not get `this.$http` as undefined.

Or you need to bind `this` in the anonymous function for token within the `created()`.

```
<script>
export default {

  props: ['plans'],
  data() {
      return{
        stripeEmail: '',
        stripeToken: '',
        plan: 3,
        status: false
      };
  },

  created(){
    this.stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: admin.stripeKey,
    image: "https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png",
    locale: "auto",
    panelLabel: "Subscribe for: ",
    email: admin.user.email,
    //here you are using function(token) within it the `this` will not reference the Vue instance, hence this.$http is undefined.
    //token: function(token){
    //so change it to use the ES2015 arrow syntax
    token:(token) => {
      this.stripeEmail = token.email;
      this.stripeToken = token.id;

      //this.$el.submit();
      this.$http.post('payments/checkout', this.$data)
          .then(
            response => alert('Thank you for your purchase!.'),
            response => this.status = response.body.status
          );

    }
  });
  },

  methods: {

    buy(){

      let plan = this.findPlanById(this.plan);

      this.stripe.open({
        name: plan.name,
        description: plan.description,
        zipCode: true,
        amount: plan.price
      });
    },

    findPlanById(id){
      return this.plans.find(plan => plan.id == id);
    }

  }

};
```

Comment: Hi Donkarnash. Yes that was the issue and it is now working fine. Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad I could be of help. If the answer solved your problem you could mark it as the answer for others visiting this question to know. Happy coding..